# ECMAScript 5 defined - common factory pattern for construction and inheritance, [ Object.create()]

Tags: javascript, inheritance

ECMAScript 5
has defined a very common factory pattern for construction and inheritance, called Object.create(). I am simply passing in the object to
inherit from, and getting back a new object all properly wired up.

Consider the snippet:

```
var a = {
    phrase: "Hello",
    say: function(){ alert(this.phrase); }
};
var b = Object.create(a);
```

Is my understanding correct as reflected below?

> When b is first created, it has a prototype-inherited property called
>   phrase, meaning that the property is not on the instance (b.phrase),
>   but actually on the prototype (b.prototype.phrase). If I were to
>   read the value of b.phrase at that point, JavaScript would implicitly
>   look it up, find it on the prototype, and return it to me.

```
b.say(); // alerts Hello
```

However, when I make the assignment of a new value to b.phrase, I see it doesn’t affects the inherited
b.prototype.phrase but have instead set (overridden) an instance property b.phrase that takes precedence over the inherited
b.prototype.phrase on future property accesses. Why?

```
b.phrase = "World";
a.say(); // alerts Hello              >> This hasn't changed. Why?
b.say(); // alerts World
```

Comment: You need to distinguish between "the prototype of `b`", and `b.prototype`. The prototype of `b` is given by `Object.getPrototypeOf(b)`, and is quite different from `b.prototype`, which is the prototype automatically given to objects constructed by `new b` (if it's a constructor).

Comment: @torazaburo: Thank you for your suggestion. Is that your real name?Indians don't have such names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of the *prototype chain*. JavaScript runtime looks for own object's properties first, and if nothing is found, it looks for the property on its prototype, and so on.

In the other hand, you're not *overriding* a property, but you are just adding one to the whole object and it *hides* the prototype's one, and again, this happens because of how prototype chain works.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way javascript property lookup/assignment work. If you want to update prototype property, you can create object inside prototype object.

```
var proto = {
    fields: {
        phrase: 'Hello'
    },
    say: function () { console.log(this.fields.phrase) }
};

var a = Object.create(proto);

a.fields.phrase = 'World';
proto.say();
a.say();
```

So, what is going on here?

`a.fields.phrase = 'World'` is equal to

```
var tmp = a.fields;
tmp.phrase = 'World';
```

`a.fields === a.__proto__.fields // true`

That is why property was updated in prototype.

In your example you just assign value to object and js engine does what you want – assigns value "World" with key "phrase" to object a, nothing weird

[More info about how objects work in js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model)

Answer (score 0):

First take this statement

```
var b = Object.create(a);
```

This statement creates a new object, `newObj`(for instance). Now following things  happen:

- b points to `newObj`.
- newObj is linked to a's object via `[[prototype]]` reference.

Till now `newObj` does not have any methods or properties.

Take `b.Say()` -- 
b will point to `newObj`,so first it tries to check whether `newObj` has `Say()` method, it doesn't have so it tries to delegate via `[[prototype]]` chain. As `newObj's` `[[prototype]]` link points to a's object. It tries to check whether `Say()` is present in a's object.So it finds the method there & execute it with the context of `newObj.` It prints `'Hello'`

Take `b.Phrase='world'`
Here you are assigning `phrase` property to `newObj` object (pointed by 'b'). So from next time if you are trying to do `b.Phrase` it will not traverse up the `[[Prototype]]` chain (i.e to a's object), instead it will find the value in `newObj` itself.

`Final b.Say()` 
As `newObj` does not have `Say()` method, it will traverse up the `[[prototype]]` chain, finds the method, & executes it in the context of `newObj`. And as `newObj` has phrase property so `this.phrase` returns `'world'`